# Вытащить элементы из массива по указанным значениям

Tags: php, foreach

Есть массив `address_o1`, вот его содержание, нужно вытащить из него только те данные, где имеется в url слово "brendy".

```
[1] => stdClass Object
     (
         [page_views] => 98
         [exit] => 16
         [url] => http://site.ru/catalog
         [id] => 11937405797355675339
         [entrance] => 5
     )

 [2] => stdClass Object
     (
         [page_views] => 80
         [exit] => 3
         [url] => http://site.ru/brendy/brends
         [id] => 13199584431525406363
         [entrance] => 3
     )

 [3] => stdClass Object
     (
         [page_views] => 73
         [exit] => 10
         [url] => http://site.ru/brendy
         [id] => 16674043290505888786
         [entrance] => 7
     )

 [4] => stdClass Object
     (
         [page_views] => 41
         [exit] => 8
         [url] => http://site.ru/cosm
         [id] => 7854648251933888664
         [entrance] => 4
     )
```

Comment: @Exsol, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($address_o1 as $v){
 if( stripos($v->url,'brendy') !== false ){
  // Определённо нашли что-то с бренди :)
 }
}
```

Comment: Блин, перепутал я местами аргументы, вот и не работала первая версия, благодарю за разъяснения.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
foreach($address_o1 as $v){
 if(preg_match('!brendy!i', $v->url){
  // Определённо нашли что-то с бренди :)
 }
}
```

Comment: Не работает :(

Comment: Тогда так, см. обновленный пост.

Comment: И так не хочет :( Что же за беда такая

Comment: Работает, я создал такой же массив элементов и проверил - всё находит и выводит.  
Кинь свой код тогда, глянем что там за фигня.

Comment: Массив получаю из яндекс метрики.
В коде только токен яндекс метрики, расшифровка json и все.
Как только вставляю код из твоего примера, страница не загружается.

Comment: Чувак, вот тестовый код:

    $data = [];
    $rand = [
        'brendy',
        ''
    ];
    for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++){
        $tmp = new stdClass();
        $tmp->page_views = rand(1, 100);
        $tmp->url = 'http://site.ru/' . $rand[rand(0, 1)];
        $tmp->name = $i;
        $data[] = $tmp;
        unset($tmp);
    }

    foreach($data as $v)
        if(preg_match('!brendy!i', $v->url)){
            print 'Found: ' . $v->name . ', URI: ' . $v->url . "\n";
        else
            print 'Obj: ' . $v->name . ', URI: ' . $v->url . "\n";

Comment: Генерирую массив объектов, как у тебя (нет некоторых свойств, но это неважно).  
Потом проверяю - и всё работает.  
Или массив у тебя всё-таки другой?